# Developing an online music store

Tags: asp.net, ftp, file-upload

We need to develop an application to sell music online. No need to specify that all will be done quite legally and in so doing, we have to plan an interface to pay artists. However, we are confronted with a question: What is the best way to store music on the server? Should we save it on server's disk from a HTTP fileupload? Should we save via FTP or would it be wiser to save it in the database? No need to say that we need it to be the most safiest as possible. So maybe an https is required here. But, we what you think is the best way? Maybe other idea? Because in all HTTP case, upload songs (for administration) is quite long and boring, but easly linkable to a song that admin create in his web application comparativly to an FTP application to upload song on server and then list directory in admin part to link the correct uploaded song to the song informations in database.

I know that its maybe not quite clear, it's because i'm french but tell me and I will try to explain part that you don't understand.

Comment: Flash or Silverlight upload controls seem to be the fastest growing method used to do this. See YouTube's video upload page for a good example.

Comment: Is there any "built-in" control in Silverlight for uploading? I've never touch it before so maybe it's a good opportunity to try learning it ... maybe someone hold great ressources to begin learning Silverlight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used [Krystalware's SlickUpload](http://krystalware.com/Products/SlickUpload/) ASP.NET control in the past to take care of the uploading part for you (you can use the in built control if you want to but this has a lot of the nifty ajax-style features done for you and is quite cheap).

Edit:
[I would not advocate storing the music file itself in the database. Much better [in my humble opinion] only to store the location of the file in the database. If you use one of the cloud services listed below then the location might simply be an HTTP link]

I'd also seriously consider using a cloud storage service for storing the music files. Something like [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) or [Rackspace Cloud Files](http://www.rackspacecloud.com/cloud_hosting_products/files). CloudFiles is good because, if you wish, you can also enable CDN delivery (Content Delivery Network) which means your users can access the uploaded music tracks much faster than if served off your local web server, for instance.

Hope this helps,

Richard.

Comment: Going the Cloud route is a good idea; especially as it means as the service grows you can add servers as required (eg Azure) with relatively low effort

Comment: Thank you! Your explanations are very clear and very constructive! We will watch it closely and from what I have read about what you
talk to me, this seems the best way forward. Thank you again!